# Rename a table via the auto-generated import data script

Tags: matlab, concatenation, variable-assignment, cell-array

I use the `auto-generated` script by `Matlab` to import a text file. However I am wondering following unsuccessful attempts (*so far*) if there exist efficient ways to rename the default table name (`out`) using a concatenation of the `subco_` variable as illustrated below:

```
subco_={12345,23456,34567,45678};
['N',num2str(subco_{1,3})] % leading to N34567 (of char type)
```

Having performed slight modifications into the section (from Matlab auto-generated script)

```
   %% Create output variable
      out = table
      out.columnames = rawCellColums(:,x) x=1...
```

I naturally end up in my workspace with the table called `out` (*so far nothing special*), however I'd like to rename:

```
   ['N',num2str(subcode_{1,3})] = out
Error: An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot contain LEX_TS_STRING.
```

I understand that the `assignment` could not merely be performed in such a way for 2 data of different data types (different dimensions, etc.) `array2table()` being *helpless*.

As a way around, I have 2  trivial **options**:

- `right-click` on `out` (in the workspace), and `rename` the latter variable to `N34567`,
- create manually `N43456` as a variable and assign it to `out`(in script); `N34567= out`

However the above way-around involve a manual intervention that I'd like to get rid off. Thus any idea on the assignment of elements to `subco_` would be appreciated.